# how to check if firewall is stopped on redhat 7

Tags: scripting, rhel, security, iptables, firewall

What is the elegant way to verify if firewall is stop/inactive on redhat 7 machines?

example:

we stop the firewall:

```
systemctl  status firewalld.service
```

and my approach to verify the firewall status is like this:

```
systemctl  status firewalld.service

● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

so

in my bash script I do the following in order to check if firewall is stopped/inactive

```
if [[ `  systemctl  status firewalld.service | grep Active | awk '{print $2}' ` = inactive ]] 
then
       firewall_status=inactive
else
       firewall_status=active
fi
```

but to check the results like this way is little clumsy.

Comment: You can use 'firewall-cmd --state'

Comment: in that case another question how to verify the iptables ?  ( instead of systemctl stop iptables.service )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RHEL 7 introduces a command `firewall-cmd` to work with firewall. But the catch is it requires root access.

If you are running your script as root, then you can use the following code:

```
if [[ `firewall-cmd --state` = running ]]
then
    firewall_status=active
else
    firewall_status=inactive
fi
```

But if you are not running your script as root, then, unfortunately, yours is the only way to do it.

Comment: in that case another question how to verify the iptables ? ( instead of systemctl stop iptables.service

Comment: According to RHEL 7 documentation [1], iptables is not installed by default. Instead it is managed by firewalld now.

Still, assuming that you have somehow enabled iptables, you will have to check that by the same method that you have mentioned. For more details, refer to this link [2].

[1] https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/migration_planning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-migration_planning_guide-security_and_access_control

[2] https://superuser.com/questions/1124317/how-to-verify-if-iptables-is-running-or-the-firewall-is-activated

Answer (score 3):

There is a better and cleaner way:

```
systemctl is-active firewalld
```

will simply return `true` if firewalld is active and running, `false` otherwise.

So your test becomes:

```
if [ `systemctl is-active firewalld` ]
then
    firewall_status=active
else
    firewall_status=inactive
fi
```

Comment: does it work on ubuntu and other distros?

Comment: I think you need the -q flag: ```if [ `systemctl -q is-active firewalld` ]```

Answer (score -1):

You can check with below command, status of firewall in Redhat Linux 7

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

You will see status -

> firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon    Loaded:
>   loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled)
>   **Active: inactive (dead)**
>
> Aug 21 14:55:54 host systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall
>   daemon... Aug 21 14:55:57 host systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic
>   firewall daemon. Sep 24 15:43:03 host systemd[1]: Stopping firewalld -
>   dynamic firewall daemon... Sep 24 15:43:04 host systemd[1]: Stopped
>   firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.